# Equivalent SQL function of IFNULL and IFF in spark dataframe

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use a Snowflake column (which has functions like IFFNULL and IFF) in Spark dataframe. I have tried coalesce but its not working. Is there any equivalent function or logic to use in Spark dataframe?

Snowflake SQL:

```sql
SELECT P.Product_ID,
IFNULL(IFF(p1.ProductDesc='',NULL,p1.ProductDesc),
           IFNULL(IFF(p2.PrdDesc='',NULL,p2.PrdDesc),IFF(p3.Product_Desc='',NULL,p3.Product_Desc))
          ) AS Product_Description
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN Product_table_1 p1 ON p1.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
LEFT JOIN Product_table_2 p2 ON p2.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
LEFT JOIN Product_table_3 p3 ON p3.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
```

I tried: `coalesce(p1.ProductDesc, p2.PrdDesc, p3.Product_Desc)` but it is not working

Comment: Try `case when...` as the general and standard replacement for such functions. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/sql/#when

Comment: Why isn't `COALESCE()` working?  That would seem like the correct code.

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, you can try coalesce + [nullif](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#nullif):

> nullif(expr1, expr2) - Returns null if expr1 equals to expr2, or expr1 otherwise.

For example (using *pyspark*):

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(None,"","a"),("a","","b"),("",None,"c")],["desc1", "desc2", "desc3"])

df.createOrReplaceTempView("tb")

spark.sql("select *, coalesce(nullif(desc1,''), nullif(desc2,''), nullif(desc3,'')) as desc from tb").show()       
+-----+-----+-----+----+
|desc1|desc2|desc3|desc|
+-----+-----+-----+----+
| null|     |    a|   a|
|    a|     |    b|   a|
|     | null|    c|   c|
+-----+-----+-----+----+
```

so for your task, use the following:

```
coalesce(nullif(p1.ProductDesc,''), nullif(p2.PrdDesc,''), nullif(p3.Product_Desc,'')) as Product_Description
```

BTW. you can also just change all `IFF` in your original SQL to `IF`.